# Struts2+ Spring : Request Paremeters dont get reset in Action objects?

Tags: java, spring, struts2, httprequest

I am developing Spring 3 + Struts2 application and I configure my Actions in Spring as follows:

```
  <bean id="patientSearchAPIClass" class="com.axiohelix.nozoki.web.action.api.PatientSearch">     
       <property name="searchService" ref="searchService"/>        
    </bean>
```

But in my Action class I keep fields to store Request parameters ,

```
public class PatientSearch extends ActionSupport {


        public String getPharumoId() {      
        return pharumoId;
        }

        public void setPharumoId(String pharumoId) {
        this.pharumoId = pharumoId;
         }

        public String getName() {
        return name;
        }
        public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        }

        private String name;
        private String pharumoId;
        ..


        public String execute(){        
        searchResults=searchService.searchPatients(pharumoId,                                                  name,
                                                   birthday,
                                                   pharmacyId,
                                                   clinic,
                                                   doctorName,
                                                   drugName,
                                                   supplyDate,                                                 
                                                   offset, 
                                                   pageSize);       

        return Action.SUCCESS;
    }
```

This Action returns a JSON output and I access it using URL like:

**http://localhost/app/searchAPI.action?name=UserName**

then next time if I access using URL :

**http://localhost/app/searchAPI.action**

The field 'name' is till set to previous "UserName" value.

1.How to reset these values per request ?

2.I thought Action classes are instantiated per request,is it not ?

Comment: are you sing struts2-spring plugin if yes change the bean scope to `prototype`since by default its singleton and S2 use Action as a Data transfer object also.like `<bean id="patientSearchAPIClass" class="com.axiohelix.nozoki.web.action.api.PatientSearch" scope=prototype>`

Comment: yes,I am using struct2-spring plugin..thanks for the tip .let me try it.

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi thanks it worked.could you post this as an answer so that i can choose it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was with the way Action classes are getting created by Spring.By default Spring creates singleton instances and for Struts2 ,Action classes also work as Model, due to this framework create a new instance of Action and place it in to values stack.

While creating action class using Spring make sure to define scope as prototype like

```
<bean id="patientSearchAPIClass" 
 class="com.axiohelix.nozoki.web.action.api.PatientSearch" scope=prototype>
```

So that new instance of Action should get created by Spring for each request.

Comment: @StevenBenitez:Yes agree, i have seen so many people even on SO with same issue while using spring as DI

Comment: I'm maintaining a Struts project with Spring. And honestly, I hate Struts because `Action` must be declare with `prototype` scope.